# Causes of CFDictionaryGetValue crash?

Tags: ios, swift, core-foundation, cfdictionary

I'm having random crashes within my swift app and they are all throwing a similar error around `CFDictionaryGetValue`

Here are two screenshots from my Google Crashlytics showing the error and that its effecting to different URLs,  ***Note these are from two separate crashes***

[image]
[image]

Then here is also a screenshot directly from within Xcode where I was able to reproduct the error:
[image]

There doesn't seem to be any specific action that causes this issue and it occurs at random times.

And advise for trying to trace it and debug would be much appreciated!

Thanks
Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out this issue was caused by a bug within the Firebase Performance SDK. After removing the SDK everything is working as expected

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6734?fbclid=IwAR0L5U4dsBjyUGmklr8qEohlKTyY7P6zJwzWUnU3dUTnFmb0aclK4-rt5os

Comment: There is an update to the FirebasePerformance SDK (7.0.1 and the more recent and stable 7.1.0) which resolves the issue. Unfortunately we got the crash on about 30% of our users using the bad version of the SDK.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at the updated SDK but conscious of adding it back in again so soon

Comment: So, we've updated to the latest FirebasePerformance SDK and the crashes have vanished from our production app (where we had ~35K crashes due to this...). It should be safe to add back in, just make sure you're using v7.1.0 or later!

Comment: Thanks Lucas! for being the guinea on this one lol :) I'll be sure to add in v7.1.0 or later

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up an Exception breakpoint, it would probably give you more information to help you debug it:

In Xcode:

- Go to *Breakpoint Navigator* (CMD+8)
- Click the + button in the bottom left corner of the navigator and then choose *Exception Breakpoint...*
- Select *All* in the Exception field
- Re-run your app and you should get clearer information in the debugger